# Problem with code to download data from chrome

Tags: r, rselenium

i'm trying to execute code from here: https://rpubs.com/mbadros/sp500history
But i'm newbie in R. I'm stuck in that block:

```
library(rJava)
library(RSelenium)

base_url <- 'https://www.ishares.com/us/products/239726/ishares-core-sp-500-etf'

rD <- rsDriver(port = 4839L, browser = c("chrome"), chromever="84.0.4147.30")
remDr <- rD$client
remDr$navigate(base_url)

test <- remDr$findElement(using = 'css selector', '#holdingsTabs li a[href*="All"]')
test$clickElement()

option_list <- remDr$findElement(using = 'css selector',
                                 '#holdingsTabs #tabsAll .date-dropdown')$selectTag()

get_top_holdings <- function(x) {
  option_list$elements[[x]]$clickElement()
  remDr$findElement(using = 'css selector', '.holdings .icon-xls-export')$clickElement()
}

lapply(1:length(option_list$value), get_top_holdings)
```

I'm getting an error:

```
Error in option_list$elements[[x]]$clickElement(): attempt to apply non-function
```

Tried to solve problem with google, but can't find solution.